# How do I open a file to view in a new tab?

Tags: tabbed-user-interface

How do I open a file to view in a new tab? Specifically, I want the read-only equivalent of `:tabe[dit] <filename>`. I have tried

```
:tab :view <filename>
```

but that does not create a new tab as the [documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tabpage.html#:tab) would suggest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`:tab <cmd>` opens a tab where a `<cmd>` would have opened a window. `:view` doesn't open a window, so `:tab view` doesn't open a tab :-) See [`:help :tab`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/tabpage.txt.html#%3Atab).

However, we also have the [`:sview`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#splitview) command, which does:

> Same as ":split", but set 'readonly' option for this buffer.

This *does* open a window. So `:tab sview file` opens a tab.

`:sview` is short for "split view". You can abbreviate to to `:sv`, and you can also leave out the second `:`.

---

Postscript:
Your question suggests you're not very familiar with Vi/Vim terminology. Many people are confused about this, so don't worry :-) [`:help window`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#window) is a good read for an introduction. It has a useful summary at the start:

> A buffer is the in-memory text of a file.
>   A window is a viewport on a buffer.
>   A tab page is a collection of windows.

Comment: Thanks. Just what I was looking for. And thanks for the primer on vi/Vim terminology. One correction: while the command is called "splitview" the `:splitview` command does not exist. It's just `:sview` or `:sv`.

Comment: @adurity Oops, thanks. That was in the help file, but I misread >_<